# Storing Time in MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a hard time storing a record of Time in MySQL using PHP and I hope someone would help me.

What I really need is to get **my computer's time** and store it into my database.
I tried using this

```
$time_in = date ("h:i:s:a:");
```

and then store it into my database, but the problem is, it's showing an **incorrect** time.(`+6:00`, I think)

So, how do I get my own computer's current time and store it as it is in my database?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's very unlikely that you get this small time difference. The main reason I can think of is that there is a 6 minute time difference between your computer and the server that runs PHP.

Comment: Have you tried using raw SQL to achieve this?

Comment: Sorry for the incorrect format @GolezTrol, that is supposed to be +6 hours and I am using my computer as the server too.

Comment: @Jonast92 I am sorry but I have no idea how to try this using raw SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Code that you need :

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta'); 
$time = date('H:i:s');
$date = date('d-m-Y');
echo "Date is ".$date."Time is ".$time;
echo $date1;
?>
```

To store it in Database :

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO date_time (Date, Time)
VALUES ('$date', '$time')");


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Note :

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
```

1. Change the Location according to yours.

Here is the List of [Supported Timezones Officially php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

1. Create a table called as date_time before running this code.

Comment: Oh I got it. I just changed the value to ('Asia/Taipei'). Thank you!

Comment: @user3727135: Kindly change the time zone to your location, date_default_timezone_set('##to your location');

Comment: I have now set the correct time zone, next is how do I store it into to my database?

Comment: mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Table (date) VALUES ($date1)"); You should create a table and a row called as date in it and you should give the proper MySqli Connections

Comment: [Mysqli Insert](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp) Here is the link to insert data using mysqli

Comment: Additionally you can get the date and time seperately by the following code. $date = date('d-m-Y'); $time = date('H:i:s');

Comment: Thank you for the information. I'll absolutely try it later and see if it works.

Comment: it did work. I am now able to store the correct time. Now all I need is to be able to update the table to input a value to an existing row.

Comment: Yes it is possible, Kindly ask it in a separate Question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the timezone settings and set it according to your region before inserting. For example:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Kentucky/Louisville');
$time_in = date("h:i:s");
// perform insertion
```

For list of supported timezones, refer [PHP Timezones](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this :

```
<?php

        $time_nowb=mktime(date('h')+11,date('i')+30,date('s')-15);  
        $added_date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s',$time_nowb);
        echo $added_date ;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use **date_default_timezone_set** for your area and use a **timestamp** field in your mysql table.

more info:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Dublin'); 
$myDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); // mysql timestamp: (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS)
mysql_query("insert into `mytable` set `mytime` = '$myDate'");

?>
```

or you can set the database timezone with an offset and use mysql date/time functions.

mysql:

```
SET time_zone='offset';
```

more info: [How do I set the time zone of MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-to-set-timezone-of-mysql)

Comment: I have now set the correct time zone, next is how do I store it into to my database?

Comment: You should create a field in your mysql table using type as TIMESTAMP. Then just insert your php date using the code attached to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your database knows your computer's time too. Just use the mysql function NOW() to add current time in your database. Something like

```
INSERT INTO mytable (mydata, created) values ("some data", NOW());
```

This works perfectly if the database is on the same computer than the executing script.

If you need to send the date of your computer to a database on a remote computer, then this is the correct way to get your current time in mysql date format

```
$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Comment: I have tried using NOW() but I need the Date and Time records to be saved in the database separately.